# How to make SignalR behave gracefully in case of disconnection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, long-polling

My application will often be used under fucked up corporate networks (proxy, firewalls, etc.) so I can not rely on sockets and long-polling is practically my only option. Here is my biggest problem with long-polling:

1. Long-polling is disconnected at some point of time
2. I automatically reconnect (accoring to documentation)
3. User clicks something that causes hub method call but connection is not established yet - error happens.

Is there any way to synchronize hub method call and reconnection like:

1. I call hub method
2. SignalR sees connection is not ready yet
3. It waits till connection is ready and calls a hub method afterall

For now I don't see such an oportunity and it seems like my only option is to switch to ajax calls which is sad.

Answer (score 2):

How I deal with it:

- have a `isConnected boolean` on my client so that whenever I connect, I set it to `true`, and whenever I disconnect I set it back to `false`:

  `$.connection.hub.start().fail((err) => { alert(err); }).done(() => this.isConnected = true);
  $.connection.hub.disconnected(() => { this.isConnected = false; });
  $.connection.hub.reconnected(() => { this.isConnected = true; });`
- now, right before I make the call to a hub method, I check if `isConnected` is true. If not, I attempt start the hub connection:

  `$("#serverButton").click(function(){
      if(this.isConnected==false)
          $.connection.hub.start();
      $.connection.hub.server.serverMethod();

  })`

This is how I handle such situations right now.
Hope this helps. Best of luck!

UPDATE: There actually exists a property on `$.connection.hub` called `state` that you can access at every point during the connection.

So you can skip the step of having your own variable (though I still use it just to be sure) by checking `$.connection.hub.state`.

`$.connection.connectionState
Object {connecting: 0, connected: 1, reconnecting: 2, disconnected: 4}`

The output from `$.connection.hub.state` is an integer from the ones above, but you can do something like this:  `$.connection.hub.state == $.signalR.connectionState.connected` and you can have booleans.

Easier, but you still have to check this every time you make a call to a hub method.

Comment: Yeah, something like that should work out. But that's crazy you have to do it for every hub method call (or introduce a wrapper). I guess there's a reason why it is not part of SignalR

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that it does not support waiting for connection to be established

Comment: You can have the actual server method call on the `.done()` callback.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it will help with the waiting if I really need this method to be executed

Comment: "I don't think it will help with the waiting if I really need this method to be executed." Could you please be a little more specific with why/what are you still unclear about? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your client can take a look if currently connected and do things accordingly. Use connection object:

```
$.signalR.connectionState
Object {connecting: 0, connected: 1, reconnecting: 2, disconnected: 4}
```

And do thing based on current state:

```
if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
  // I am online
}
```

Waiting for connection to be established:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    // Now the connection is established
}
```

Waiting for your method to finish:

```
yourHub.server.yourMethod(param1, param2).done(function() {
    // Now yourMethod is finished
}
```