# SignalR status of the connection

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Makes messaging on SignalR. Client - .NET 4.5 local application.
       I do not know how to check the status of the connection with the client on the server side. The fact is that when connecting the user logs in the server. And if you disable a user account is deleted from the server. 
If the client application is not completed normally, for example as a result of exceptions, On Disconnected method on the server is not called, and the user account is not deleted. 
Tell me how you can solve the problem, if anyone knows.

Comment: [Have a look at this answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32312029/3084239) If you didn't find what you are looking for, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that SignalR is smart enough to handle disconnection and remove the disconnected client from the group automatically, so no need to worry about the anormal disconnect events.

Comment: In this case signalR not reconnecting .  After internet connection lost need some code for reconecting

Comment: I think reconnecting is not server's problem. Its must be done in client code. There is a event for reconnecting so handle it in clint side.